# Closing Chrome window or better solution

Tags: google-chrome, autoit

I'm new to AutoIt and have a program mostly working.

Objective: Open a website in a browser and then close it after a given period of time (1.5 hours).

Script:

```
;Open a command prompt to start chrome from.
Run("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
WinWaitActive("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
send('"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://website.com' & "{ENTER}")
;Close the dos box
WinWaitActive("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
send('exit' & "{ENTER}")
; 5400000 = 1.5 hours
sleep( 5400000 );
WinWaitActive("Listen Live - Google Chrome","")
;Send("{F4}{ALTUP}")
Send("{CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}q{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}")
```

The opening works just fine but the script never closes. It appears to work when the timer is very short but not when it is that long.

The script will be executed via Windows Scheduled tasks. I've tried separating the open/close into two separate scripts but that didn't seem to work either.

I'm open to alternative solutions that will work on Windows.

Comment: When you state that it works when the timer is short, are you executing it via the Windows Scheduled tasks? Depending on what version of Windows and what settings you have on the scheduled task, Windows may not be able to interact with the desktop (in other words, the task may not "see" your open windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the last WinWaitActive to WinActivate *might* resolve your issue, but getting the window handle and closing via that would probably be a better way.

Also, be certain that the window title you are looking for really exists. I noticed my Google Chrome window titles do not actually have " - Google Chrome" in them. Confirm this by opening up the web page and the use the Auto Window Info application. That application will show you the exact Window title and other information when you click/activate a window. And you don't have to have an exact match. For example, if the window title may differ after "Listen Live - xxxx", then just look for "Listen Live -".

Try the code below and see how it works:

```
; set variables
$browser_exe = "c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
$URL = "http://website.com"
$window_title = "Listen Live - Google Chrome"
$sleep_time = 5400000 ; 1.5 hours

; run the browser and pass the URL to it
Run($browser_exe & " " & $URL)

; get window handle
$window_handle = WinWait($window_title)

Sleep($sleep_time)

; close the window
WinClose($window_handle)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked I need to send it to the person that wanted it to see if it works in their scheduler.